# How to get BASH to use * wildcard in command?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I've created a bash script to automate editing the EXIF data in image files. I can't figure out how to get the script to issue a command with the * wildcard (asterisk) to specify a file name pattern.

The script properly assembles a CLI command that executes properly if I enter it manually outside of the bash script. But from within bash, the script returns a file not found error.

Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Usage: Place this script in the directory of jpg files whose EXIF data is to be edited.

echo Press enter to accept default values.

# Enter camera manufacturer.
default="Pentax"
read -p "Enter camera manufacturer [$default]: " cameramake
cameramake=${cameramake:-$default}
exifargs="-model=$cameramake"

# Enter camera model.
default="K1000"
read -p "Enter camera model [$default]: " cameramodel
cameramodel=${cameramodel:-$default}
exifargs="$exifargs -make=$cameramodel"

# Enter slide film type.
default="Kodachrome slide film."
read -p "Enter slide film type [$default]: " filmtype
filmtype=${filmtype:-$default}
exifargs="$exifargs -imagedescription='PIE PS-5000 slide scanner. VueScanner 32 scanning softare. $filmtype'"

# Enter file name pattern.
default="*.jpg"
read -p "Enter file name pattern [$default]: " namepattern
namepattern=${namepattern:-$default}
exifargs="$exifargs $default"

#Use exiftool to edit EXIF data
echo /home/richard/Dropbox/Pictures/Tools/ExifTool/exiftool "$exifargs"
/home/richard/Dropbox/Pictures/Tools/ExifTool/exiftool "$exifargs"
```

I inserted the "echo" command to check that my command is correct. It is (at leats for the CLI). The results of running the script is:

```
richard@richard-laptop:~/Dropbox/Pictures/Photos/test$ sh exifbatch.sh
Press enter to accept default values.
Enter camera manufacturer [Pentax]: 
Enter camera model [K1000]: 
Enter slide film type [Kodachrome slide film.]: 
Enter file name pattern [*.jpg]: 
/home/richard/Dropbox/Pictures/Tools/ExifTool/exiftool -model=Pentax -make=K1000 -imagedescription='PIE PS-5000 slide scanner. VueScanner 32 scanning softare. Kodachrome slide film.' *.jpg
No file specified
```

But when I enter the exact same text as create by the script on the command line, it functions as I want, finding the files in the current directory that match the name pattern. (The warnings thrown by exiftool are expected.):

```
richard@richard-laptop:~/Dropbox/Pictures/Photos/test$ /home/richard/Dropbox/Pictures/Tools/ExifTool/exiftool -model=Pentax -make=K1000 -imagedescription='PIE PS-5000 slide scanner. VueScanner 32 scanning softare. Kodachrome slide film.' *.jpg
Warning: [minor] Ignored empty rdf:Seq list for darktable:mask_id - 1987_California-01.jpg
Warning: [minor] Ignored empty rdf:Seq list for darktable:mask_id - 1987_California-02.jpg
2 image files updated
```

How do I change my basch script so that the command will executed as it does on the CLI?  I think there's something wrong with how I'm using the * character. If I don't put quotation marks (") around the $exifargs variable name, bash immediately interprets the *.jpg and appends all the file names into the string, which then confounds the exiftool command.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "which then confounds the exiftool command"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting in shell is tricky. If you want to use several parameters, especially when some of them contain whitespace, use arrays. Note that you need real `bash` to run the script to use arrays, so don't start the script with `sh`, which runs `dash` instead, with no array support.

```
args=( -model="$cameramake"
       -make="$cameramodel"
       -imagedescription="PIE PS-5000 slide scanner. VueScanner 32 scanning softare. $filmtype"
       $namepattern )
exiftool "${args[@]}"
```

BTW, are you sure you want to name the variable holding the model "make" and naming the variable holding the maker "model"? Also note that "software" has a *w* after *t*.

Comment: That worked like a dream!  You da man (or da woman, but your avatar sure looks beardy for a woman...)!

Comment: BTW @choroba, does the `[@]` instruct bash to use all arguments inside the array?

Comment: @trinkner: Yes, it does. Try searching around `man bash` for details.